# apache 2.4 ProxyPassMatch use "-"

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

i have tried create a proxy comunication between my 2 localhost host

i want create a proxy for all uri from http://my-webapp.localhost/test-nc/mnm/rest to http://other.localhost/mnm/rest

this is my proxy configuration

```
    ProxyPass /test-nc/mnm/rest http://other.localhost/mnm/rest
    ProxyPassReverse /test-nc/mnm/rest http://other.localhost/mnm/rest
    Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
    ProxyPassMatch ^/test\-nc/mnm/rest/(.*) http://other.localhost/mnm/rest/$1
```

this not work, but if use in from uri other **test-nc** without "-" (dash) work fine

### this work (but i MUST use test-nc)

call from http://my-webapp.localhost/testnc/mnm/rest/aa/1/as2serverrules to http://other.localhost/mnm/rest/aa/1/as2serverrules

```
    ProxyPass /testnc/mnm/rest http://other.localhost/mnm/rest
    ProxyPassReverse /testnc/mnm/rest http://other.localhost/mnm/rest
    Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
    ProxyPassMatch ^/testnc/mnm/rest/(.*) http://other.localhost/mnm/rest/$1
```

how to use "-" inside a url in proxy configuration correctly?

Comment: **ProxyPass /testnc/mnm/rest http://other.localhost/mnm/rest** only with this work fine, but always not work if i use **ProxyPass /test-nc/mnm/rest http://other.localhost/mnm/rest**

Answer (score 0):

one solution is replace proxypass with rewriterule

RewriteRule /test-nc/mnm/rest/(.*) http://other.localhost/mnm/rest/$1 [NE,P],

but i can not have find any solution for proxyPass